# AngularJS show certain categories only

Tags: angularjs

I think this is a long shot but lets hope somebody can help me, below is the I think that part which gets all of the categories, but I only want to show certain categories instead of showing all categories. In the image i have the full category but i want the material part not to appear but still has the search functionality in the background.`[enter code

```html
<div class="ng-cloak" ng-app="angularDemo" ng-cloak="">
  <div ng-controller="angularController as ctrl">
    <div class="hidden-xs" id="filter_desktop" layout="row">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-2" style="padding-left: 0px;margin-left: -47px;margin-right: 46px;">&nbsp;
          <div class="filter" style="color: #999;font-weight: 100;font-size: 120%;margin-right: -60px;"><span>FILTER YOUR SEARCH</span></div>

          <div class="resetFilter">
            <center class="text-left" style="color: #999;"><button id="resetFilter" onclick="window.location.href='" type="button"><img alt="" src="/Data/Sites/1/media/collection/reset-icon-614x460.png" style="height: 30px!important;" />RESET FILTERS</button></center>
          </div>

          <div class="sidebar" style="border-top: 1px solid #c1c1c1;">
            <div ng-repeat="filter in Filters" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #c1c1c1;">
              <div class="col-sm-1" style="margin-right: -30px;"><button ng-click="filter.expanded = false" ng-if="filter.expanded" style="margin-left: 140px; background-color: transparent;border: none;font-size: 25px;margin-top: -34px;">+</button><button ng-click="filter.expanded = true" ng-if="!filter.expanded"
                  style="margin-left: 140px;background-color: transparent;border: none;font-size: 45px;margin-top: -34px;">-</button></div>

              <h3 class="sort" style="font-size: 18px;font-weight: 100;text-transform: uppercase;margin-bottom: 15px;">{{filter.name}}</h3>

              <div class="sortoptions" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
                <div data-hidden-checkbox="{{ filter.name == 'family'}}" ng-if="!filter.expanded" ng-repeat="option in filter.options | orderBy: 'value'" style="line-height: 1.6;"><input id="{{option.value}}" ng-checked="option.IsIncluded" ng-model="option.IsIncluded" style="margin-bottom: -1px!important;" type="checkbox" /> <label for="{{option.value}}">{{option.value}}</label></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3ooJ.jpg)`

Comment: Did you try using ngIf or ngHide for that particular category?

Comment: I would like to apply that but dunno how because i am not well verse in coding. I am just beginer still taking baby steps. Could you like show me string of code which i can try on?

Comment: Can you share a link to reproducible example like Stackblitz?

Comment: https://codepen.io/thelifenadine/pen/rammwv

Comment: My filter coding is similar to this. I adapted the coding from this in codepen. Using this how do i remove the color filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Codepen example, just add

```
ng-if="filter.name !== 'color'"
```

where you loop through the filters list (`ng-repeat`). This will only render the div if filter's name is not *color*.
[Here](https://codepen.io/rajatkhare/pen/rNOWwGL) is the updated Codepen.

Comment: I need it to also be able to remove more than 1 category and also not the category but just one of the filter within the category..will be grateful if you can guide me. thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the && operator to add multiple conditions. For the filter too, use ng-if like I used here.

Comment: <div ng-repeat="filter in Filters" ng-if="filter.name !== color && type">

Comment: Yeah, something like this.

Comment: Sorry I tried the above code but it didnt work. Perhaps you can show me on the plunker?

Comment: Which additional category and filter do you want to remove?

Comment: I would like to remove colour & size and also the filter below the "weird". Thanks for helping. Real nub at this.

Comment: That's fine. Everyone starts as a noob. Updated Codepen. Please upvote my answer too.